# Cannot determine between plist and sqlite3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, sqlite

I have been debating between a .plist and a sqlite3 database to hold some data that I need to access, but not manipulate within the .plist/database.  Here is my question.  Lets say I want to store the height and color of  trees, flowers, bushes and I want each piece of information to be accessible.  Below is similar to what I would like:**Trees** *Palm* 6 feet Green *Willow* 8 feet Brown **Bushes** *Evergreen* 5 feet Green *Cinquefoil* 2 feet Yellow **Flowers** *Rose* 1 foot Red *Tulips* 2 feet Yellow

So if I want to individually access the 2 feet height under Tulips and display it in a text box in my app..what is the best form of data store/resource to use.  .plist or sqlite?  How would I lay this out as a .plist?
As always, I appreciate your time and efforts!!
Thanks!

Comment: how big the data is though? 10 000s trees flowers or just hundred of them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It is not going to be overly huge.  I understand the .plist gets loaded before hand and that could be an issue.
I am thinking 50 or so of each at the MAX.

Comment: I have a list with about a 1000 items. I used plist and don't regret my decision. It was simple to implement.

Comment: sounds like .plist is the way to go.  I am just not positive on how to lay it out.  Would Trees, Bushes, and Flowers be their own Dictionary?

Comment: If you are not going to update the data stored. Easiest would be plist. If frequent updates are there sqlite would be better.

Comment: How do you want to search and find items. Do you just want to find items that are equal or under 2 feet? How about their Parents?

Comment: @Anupdas I am actually going to be pulling a random value from each of the categories in the plist (trees, flowers, bushes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dont have much data just use  a `.plist` it would be easier to manage

make each parent Trees,Flowers,Bushes and array make each child item a dictinary , so when you check if a child is satisfies your requirement like `2 feet height under Tulips`  use it.

create some plist like this:

[image]

Code Sample:
Note:I didnt test this you need to improve this

you can use some kind of logic here like this to check the color,kind or height.

I am giving an example from my project for you to see how you would filter the plist, so change the name of the function as you wish.

I won't  change function names cause "nobody aint got time for that" :)
create a nsobject class called `ParseSchedulePlist`

in ParseSchedulePlist .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ParseSchedulePlist : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary * agendaDic;
- (void)passStringToAgendaDic:(NSString *)string;
//trees
-(NSArray*)getTrees;
-(NSDictionary*)getItems:(NSInteger ) section ;
-(NSString*)getItemKind :(NSInteger ) section;
-(NSString*)getItemColor :(NSInteger ) section;
-(NSNumber*)getItemheight :(NSInteger ) section;
//flowers
//do the same of above for flowers an bushes took
@end
```

in ParseSchedulePlist .m

```
#import "ParseSchedulePlist.h"

@implementation ParseSchedulePlist
@synthesize agendaDic = _agendaDic;
- (void)passStringToAgendaDic:(NSString *)string {
    //get plist from bundle
        NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:string ofType:@".plist"];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
        NSLog(fileExists ? @"Yes" : @"No");
        NSLog(@"Path is %@",path);
        NSLog(@"agendaDic is  %u",[self.agendaDic count]);
        self.agendaDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];   
}
-(NSArray*)getTrees
{
    NSArray * value = [[self agendaDic]  objectForKey:@"trees"];
    return value;
}
-(NSDictionary*)getItems:(NSInteger ) section
{
    NSDictionary * value =[[self getTrees] objectAtIndex:section];
    return value;
}
-(NSString*)getItemKind :(NSInteger ) section;
{
    NSString * value =[[[self getItems] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"kind"];
    return value;
}

-(NSString*)getItemColor :(NSInteger ) section
{
    NSString * value =[[[self getItems] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"color"];
    return value;
}

-(NSNumber *)getItemheight :(NSInteger ) section;
{
    NSNumber * value =[[[self getItems] objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"height"];
    return value;
}

//write the same functions for flowers and bushes

@end
```

in your regular view controller .h:

```
#import "ParseSchedulePlist .h"
@property (nonatomic, strong) ParseSchedulePlist *agenda;
```

in your regular view controller .m:

```
#import "ParseSchedulePlist .h"
@synthesize agenda;

//here calls for the special class
    self.agenda=[[ParseSchedulePlist alloc] init];
    [self.agenda passStringToAgendaDic:@"name of the plist"];

    NSMutableArray *newArray=[ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //here for example get all the palm trees under 6 feet
    for(int i=0; i<[self.agenda getTrees] count] i++)
    {
       if([self.agenda getItemKind :i] isquealtostring @"palm"){
             if([self.agenda getItemheight :i] <= 6)
                 [newArray add object:[self.agenda getItems:i];
        }
    }
     Nslog(@"print your array %@",newArray);
```

Comment: +1 For putting an effort to create the plist. But again a doubt, how are you going to filter the children? Can you clarify the point?

Comment: @Anupdas Working on that, will update my answer with a sample code soon

Comment: are you saying it will be an issue accessing the child data under each array?

Comment: @SpaceDust Please take your time to do it. Meanwhile I would try to do it with sqlite, with two tables. If core data was in picutre it would have been a cake walk.

Comment: I am not entirely opposed to using core data.  I just don't have much experience with it.  How could this be layed out using Core Data?

Comment: @hansoac If you are using Core Data, you would need to make two entities. A Parent and Child. Parent would have one to many relationship to child and child would have one to one. Thats it. I never dared to use Core Data as such, always used it along with [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

Comment: @hansoac relax I use plist all the time, you need to find your way to filter them though, above my code sample improve and use it.

Comment: @SpaceDust wow..that looks excellent!  Thank you for your input and time to provide all of this!  You really helped me out.  I will begin developing my .plist now.

Comment: @Anupdas I am still curious how simple it would be using Core Data!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with core data. Core data as such would be a little difficult to use. I have always used it with Magical Record, a wonderful library.

It's very easy to map objects with relation. In your case there is one to many and one to one relation between parent and child.

[image]

With MagicalRecord if you wanted to find an item with height equal to 2. You can do this in two simple steps

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"height =%@",@2];
NSArray *items = [Item findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Good thing is that since there is a one to one relationship from an item to group, each item will have info about group. So everything nicely fits and it's easier to search what ever way you like.

You can find the [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoPlistStructures.zip) for the details.

Comment: excellent example, thank you for your time on this.  I need to research more and become more familiar with core data as it seems beneficial for many things

Comment: @hansoac You should thank me by giving upvote ;). BTW I have used groupID and itemID respectively as it makes working with MagicalRecord very easy.

Comment: I tried to do that originally.  However, I am 2 reputation points away from being able to do so :/  So close!!  Any suggestions on getting 2 more points? haha

Comment: @hansoac That's ok, you need atleast 10 points to do an upvote.